# Is this bash script going to start over the loop after one script dies?

Tags: python, bash, loops, terminal

I am working on a group project using Ubuntu, but my Azure VM is not working right now and I am waiting for my partner to reboot it later.

For now, I am writing a loop to constantly run these Python scripts. One is a login script and one is a register script to authenticate a user logging into our website. Every time a user logs in or registers, the scripts stop and I be manually restarting the script for it to go again. And writing a while true loop in those scripts will only cause problems.

I am writing a bash script to call all two of these. So the ampersand will run them simultaneously. So my question is this loop. When one of the scripts die, does the loop start itself over and rerun both scripts?

```
while true
    do
        python3 testdb2.py &
        python3 testdb2_register.py
    done
```

Comment: By dying do you mean exit with exception? In that case, there will be an error, but the script will continue as normal.

Comment: @gnahum yes assuming no errors are printing

Answer (score 1):

The shell script will block once you run `testdb2_register.py`, as it will wait for that script to exit before continuing with the next iteration of the loop. It doesn't matter what happens to `testdb2.py`.

Further, when `testdb2_register.py` *does* exit, `testdb2_register.py` will be started a second time. If the first one is still running, you will have two instances of the script running at once. If that's not desirable, you should kill it before starting the loop over.

```
while true
do
   python3 testdb2.py &
   python3 testdb2_register.py
   kill $!  # kill the most recent background job, i.e., testdb2.py
done
```